# Qual é a maneira correta de enviar um formulário para uma controller via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, .net, mvc

Tenho um formulário simples, que é basicamente minha ViewModel. Estou fazendo um post via AJAX passando este formulário, porém, no lado do servidor, tudo sempre está null. Meu AJAX é o seguinte:

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: '/configuracaocomercial/Create',
    type: "post",
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    data: { viewModel: formData },
    success: function (data) {
        // meu callback
    }
});
```

Eu havia lido em uma pergunta no SO em inglês, que o problema poderia ser o contentType, por isso coloquei esse `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`. Porém, meu problema persiste. No lado do servidor, eu recebo ela simplesmente:

```
[HttpPost]
public ResultadoAjax Create(ConfiguracaoComercialViewModelEdit viewModel)
{
    // Aqui, a viewModel já vem null
    // meu código
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Retire viewmodel e coloca `data: formData` e teste

Comment: @VirgilioNovic funcionou, o problema é que tenho que passar mais um parâmetro pra função

Comment: @ArturoTemplário até coloquei como resposta, qual parametro? que precisa a mais???

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar na view o seguinte comanda:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ACTION", "CONTROLLER",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnBegin = "$.fn.ExibirLoading();",
    OnSuccess = "CarregarServicoTerceiroServicoComplete(data);",
    OnFailure = "$.fn.VerifyError(xhr, status, error);",
    OnComplete = "$.fn.OcultarLoading();$('#FormCadastrarServico')[0].reset();"
}, new { @id = "FormCadastrarServico" }))
                    {
    //SEU FORMULARIO    
}
```

Ae o .net chamará automaticamente via ajax, acredito que esta seja a melhor maneira.

Os métodos `OnBegin`, `OnSuccess`, `OnFailure`, `OnComplete` chamarão js para as ações citadas.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que pude perceber tem um item atrapalhando que é o `viewModel`, acredito que deva fazer isso:

***Troque isso***

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: '/configuracaocomercial/Create',
    type: "post",
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    data: { viewModel: formData },
    success: function (data) {
        // meu callback
    }
});
```

***por isso:***

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: '/configuracaocomercial/Create',
    type: "post",
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
        // meu callback
    }
});
```

Comment: Excelente, desse jeito de baixo ele passou a viewModel. Mas eu tenho mais um parâmetro pra passar, por isso meu AJAX estava daquela maneira. A assinatura original do método é: `public ResultadoAjax Create(ConfiguracaoComercialViewModel viewModel, List<ProdutoTabela> produtos_tabela)`

Comment: Dentro do `<form>` tem essa lista de `ProdutoTabela`, porque, se tiver corretamente é assim também???, então depende do formulário! @ArturoTemplário

Comment: O List<ProdutoTabela> eu monto na mão. Engraçado que se eu passo um de cada vez, funciona

Comment: é porque existe uma forma de passar, o problema é como você está passando, entendeu @ArturoTemplário, e uma coisa isso não está na pergunta original, se poderia abrir uma nova pergunta para esse determinado paramento, o que acha!